# Get pixel coordinates of point in stacked series

Tags: echarts

In order to make my own markPoint div (since I cannot get Echarts markPoints to show up), I need to get the x,y pixel coordinates of a **visual** point on a stacked line chart where one series hits a 0 value. But because it is stacked, that 0 point isn't at the bottom of the chart, but somewhere higher sitting on top of other series lower in the stacking order.  the echartsInstance.convertToPixel function is responding back with the y pixel coordinate at the bottom of the chart, where absolute 0 would be, but that's not where the series is. It's higher up, even with a 0 value, due to stacking.

Is there anyway, maybe through getModel() or getZr() to find out what the pixel coordinates are for a series (where it actually appears visually after stacking) at a given set of its own x,y values?

Answer (score 2):

OK, let's imagine that you have a bar chart and you want to place the markPoint on the top of second bar, drawing the chart:

```
  var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

  var option = {
    xAxis: {
      data: ["A", "B", "C"]
    },
    yAxis: {},
    series: [{
      name: 'Series1',
      type: 'bar',
      data: [5, 20, 36],
    }]
  }

  myChart.setOption(option);
```

Then you should define the markPoint in series config:

```
// ...
markPoint: {
  symbol: 'circle',
  symbolSize: 10,
  itemStyle: { color: 'black' },
  data:[{
    // here you defined: x = 'B' and y = '20'
    coord: ['B', 20]
  }]
}
// ...
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/creadone/yvfn21op/) you can find the full example.

Next. You want to place the div point with pixel coordinates depending on the size of bar. Here you convert the pixel coordinates into Echarts scale:

```
var [chartX, chartY] = myChart.convertToPixel({ seriesIndex: 0 }, [x, y]);
```

You need function to draw point on page:

```
  function Point(opts){
    var { x,y } = opts;
    var canvas = document.getElementById('main');
    var point  = document.createElement('div');
        point.classList.add('point');
    var [chartX, chartY] = myChart.convertToPixel({ seriesIndex: 0 }, [x, y]);
        point.style.left = chartX + 'px';
        point.style.top  = chartY + 'px';
    return canvas.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', point);
  }
```

and then call it:

```
var p1 = new Point({ x: 'B', y: 20 });
```

It's all. See [full example](https://jsfiddle.net/creadone/8tev5pn2/).

Comment: Hi! Do you know why the seriesIndex does not affect the position returned by convertToPixel() ? The problem is very weel explained by someone else here https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/12897

Comment: Don't know. Maybe `convertToPixel` calculate coordinates before applying styles like padding, margin, borders e.t.c